# How to maintain url in codeigniter for pages,categories,subcategories and product?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to do URL format likes below

for pages -

> www.example.com/page-name

for categories

> www.example.com/category-name/sub-category-name

for product

> www.example.com/category-name/sub-category-name/product-name

or

> www.example.com/product-name

is this possible ? if yes mean how should be my controllers and functions ? should I any changes in routes.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution for your problem :)

1) If you use HMVC (https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/) that determine priority for example (example module: front):

- page_name (controller: Page)
- product_name (controller: Product)
- categories (controller: Categories)

next in routes:

```
$route['(:any)'] = function ($slug)
{
        return 'front/page/show/'.$slug;
};
```

next check in controller Page check exists there is a link. If not exists that run next controller Product. for example:

```
...
public function show($slug='')
    {
    $this->load->model('page_m');
    $page = $this->page_m->GetRowBySlug($slug)->row();
        if(!$page) {
            echo modules::run('front/product/show', $slug);
            exit;
        }
...
```

next in controller Product add to same but if not exists link run next controller etc:

```
...
public function show($slug='')
    {
    $this->load->model('product_m');
    $page = $this->product_m->GetRowBySlug($slug)->row();
        if(!$page) {
            echo modules::run('front/categories/show', $slug);
            exit;
        }
...
```

2) If not use HMVC that you can run other controller:

```
...
$this->load->library('../controllers/product');
$this->product->show($slug)
...
```

And you must change routes:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "page/show/$1";
```

Sorry for my english but I tried...

Answer (score 0):

for pages: 
Make the name of your controller the same as the name of your page.

for Category: 
Make the name of the controller the same as the name of your category.
The sub categories are the methods in the category controller.
Product name be the identity of the product that you pass on the url through anchor.

I guess this should do the job.